# SanFrancisco (.SFUIText, .SFUI-Regular) fonts issue on iOS 13

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

After updating to iOS 13 my fonts failed.
In my App.xaml I had:

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="FontFamilyRegular" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
   <On Platform="iOS">.SFUIText</On>
</OnPlatform>
<OnPlatform x:Key="FontFamilyMedium" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
   <On Platform="iOS">.SFUIText-Medium</On>
</OnPlatform>
<OnPlatform x:Key="FontFamilyBold" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
   <On Platform="iOS">.SFUIText-Semibold</On>
</OnPlatform>
```

It all worked fine until I updated my device to iOS 13.

I debugged iOS project and find out that font names could be changed to: .SFUI-Regular, .SFUI-Semibold - but these do not work neither. Also I tried updating to the latest Xamarin version - no luck.

How can I use these 3 font families in the newest iOS version?

Comment: Can you try delete all the San Francisco fonts in your project or computer and download the newest version, then try again to see if it works.

Comment: @jackhua-msft I am very curious how deleting fonts from the computer could affect loading of fonts by an iOS application running on an iOS device. Could you elaborate? And FWIW, I am having the same problem, tried downloading the SF fonts from Apple and that didn't help.

Comment: @RyanR Just an idea to see if apple updated those fonts in iOS.

Comment: I have created appropriate issue on github: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8035

Answer (score 5):

System fonts like this are now longer reference-able with 'dot' / `.` notation as per:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/

Starting with iOS 13, you can utilise the new enum `UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign`, using `regular`, `rounded`, `serif` or `monospaced`.

An example of how to create font using descriptors in Swift (see how I'm using the `design` parameter):

```
extension UIFont {

    convenience init?(
        style: UIFont.TextStyle,
        weight: UIFont.Weight = .regular,
        design: UIFontDescriptor.SystemDesign = .default) {

        guard let descriptor = UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: style)
            .addingAttributes([UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.traits: [UIFontDescriptor.TraitKey.weight: weight]])
            .withDesign(design) else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(descriptor: descriptor, size: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but I was asking about Xamarin.Form where we do not have an access to UIFont.